# get Generated Query of Entity in Symfony to debug the Query

Tags: postgresql, symfony

using Entity in Symfony to add Records.

```
use C2Educate\ToolsBundle\Entity\Notes;

$sNote = new Notes();
$sNote->setNote($note);
$sNote->setAdditionalNote($addtionalNote);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($sNote);
```

i want to see the query.

Comment: Use Symfony Profiler.

Comment: Cant we print the Query .?

Comment: The query is assembled just before it's executed. It's just much easier to simply look into Symfony's profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Symfony Profiler.**

The query is assembled just before it's executed. It's just much easier to simply look into Symfony's profiler.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just see log file and see query like so

`cd your_project
tail -f var/logs/*`

Answer (score -1):

1. You can activate postgresql log and see the query there. In your data/postgresql.conf file, change the `log_statement` setting to `'all'`
2. Check in your symfony profiler on db page
3. Set breakpoint inside `LoggerChain:startQuery` and catch it